# missing device or architecture after '-mmcu='

Tags: linux, arduino, microcontroller

I'm using an Arduino package called Arduino-makefile or Arduino-mk to program Arduino Uno from the command line. Recently I wanted to program an ATtiny85 microcontroller (MC). This is my makefile:

```
    ################ MAKEFILE ###################################
    ARDUINO_DIR = /usr/share/arduino
    ###################################################
    ISP_PROG = usbasp
    ALTERNATE_CORE = attiny-master
    BOARD_TAG = attiny
    BOARD_SUB = attiny85
    F_CPU = 16000000L
    ###################################################
    include /usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk

    # !!! Important. You have to use 'make ispload' when using an ISP.
```

this is what I want to upload to the Attiny85 MC:

```
int led = 3;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {                
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);     
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

Here are the instructions for making the makefile: [Makefile](https://github.com/sudar/Arduino-Makefile/blob/master/examples/ATtinyBlink/Makefile)
I also downloaded this [boards.txt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/damellis/attiny/master/boards.txt) file.
To upload the code into the MC I use the command `sudo make upload` which did not work, so I then used `sudo make ispload`. Both of these commands gave the error message:

```
avr-g++: error: missing device or architecture after ‘-mmcu=’
/usr/share/arduino/Arduino.mk:1215: recipe for target 'build-attiny-attiny85/ATtinyBlink.o' failed
make: *** [build-attiny-attiny85/ATtinyBlink.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing the `BOARD_TAG` and only have the `BOARD_SUB` one.